# How to negate a variable in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I am trying to negate a variable using a groovy script but it does not seem to work using (!) , the variables are passed from a jenkins control running a groovy build flow:

```
def P = "arg"
def resolver = build.buildVariableResolver
def V = resolver.resolve(P)
 print "V is " + V
 print "negated V is " + !V
```

in both prints i get the same value!!

Comment: What is the type of `V`? Try: `!(V as Boolean)`.

Comment: No it did not work, V is defined as a Boolean parameter.
!(V as Boolean) i got the same value which is either all true or all false for the print statements

Comment: Strange. `assert false == !true` works well. Could you provide runnable example. Unfortunately this isn't.

Comment: Yes that works but how would assertion help me, I need to negate a variable, I think there is no operation for that in Groovy !
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Truth

Comment: please provide the type.  e.g. `println V.getClass()`; with a real plain boolean above code works fine in a 2.4 groovysh.

Comment: class java.lang.String

Comment: how do i switch to boolean !!!

Comment: and what is the value?

Comment: Whatever i pass from Jenkins using a check box

Comment: that really is helpful.  how about printing it?

Comment: println V.getClass() 
println P.getClass() 

class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String

Comment: arg is the name of the checkbox

Comment: what is the value of `V`?  what does `"V is " + V` print?

Comment: either false or true depending if the check box is checked or not

Comment: V is false V negated is false

Comment: Perhaps this may help you: assert 'random-string'==!'random-string'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use either Java's `Boolean.valueOf()` or Groovy's `String.toBoolean()` to get a proper boolean value from a String, which is either `true` or `false`.

```
def mybool = "false"
def v = Boolean.valueOf(mybool)
println "v=" + v
// => v=false
println "!v=" + !v
// => !v=true
```

`String.toBoolean()` is much more flexible and allows a wider range of of "truthy" strings (`true`, `y`, `1`, all trimmed and the case ignored).

```
def b = "False"
def v = b.toBoolean()
println "v=" + v
// => v=false
println "!v=" + !v
// => !v=true
```

While these are the remedies for the problem, the original code behaved like it did because of an implict cast. `!"false"` is `false` (the boolean), as `"false"` is by groovy standards `true` (a non-empty-string).

Comment: The value is coming from a variable, this is just hard coding false into a variable

Comment: of course it also works with a variable.  i have changed the code.